# upload file into iphone app via ftp

Tags: iphone, ftp, file-upload, wifi

I wish upload a file into my iphone app via ftp ( wifi connection on iphone) like some program as airsharing or iFiles..

which are the first steps to do this??

thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Have you get any idea to do so ? I have same requirement to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone SDK does not have a built-in FTP server, so you will have to implement a simple FTP server yourself.

First, get an overview of the FTP protocol [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol). Read the actual RFCs, which document the protocol, in the 'Further Reading' section. Some of the external links are helpful for understanding the flow of an FTP transfer.

Next, brush up on iPhone socket communication. The [Apple documentation for `CFSocket` is a good starting point](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFSocketRef/Reference/reference.html). Consider using the [AsyncSocket library](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/) to ease implementation.

Comment: thanks! I'll try... and are there some other way to put a file into the app using the wifi?

Answer (score 0):

You would begin by creating an FTP server in your application.